# How do I fix AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta' in Python

Tags: python, datetime

I've been working on some code to track stocks and have been using the datetime function to get x number or days ago, decided by user input. However, I have been getting the error

line 12, in 
amount_Of_Days_Ago = today - datetime.datetime.timedelta(days=amount_Of_Days_Ago)
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta'

Here's my code

```
import datetime

print('How many days ago should the smaller period of time be?')

amount_Of_Days_Ago = input()

amount_Of_Days_Ago = int(amount_Of_Days_Ago)

today = datetime.datetime.now()

amount_Of_Days_Ago = today - datetime.datetime.timedelta(days=amount_Of_Days_Ago)

amount_Of_Days_Ago = amount_Of_Days_Ago.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
today = today.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

amount_Of_Days_Ago = str(amount_Of_Days_Ago)
today = str(today)

response = requests.get("http://api.marketstack.com/v1/eod?access_key=###########&symbols=AAPL&date_from=" + amount_Of_Days_Ago + "&date_to=" + today)

print(response)
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, there is only the need to call `datetime` once after importing it.
Have a look at the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html). Consider using:

```
amount_Of_Days_Ago = today - datetime.timedelta(days=amount_Of_Days_Ago)
```

Or:

```
from datetime import timedelta
amount_Of_Days_Ago = today - timedelta(days=amount_Of_Days_Ago)
```

Comment: How does it not? OP has a problem with the import, and I am explicitely addressing this issue and proposing a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the *timedelta* function from the datetime library. As in:

```
     import datetime
     from datetime import timedelta
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using datetime from datetime.datetime you are getting an error.
Look into the following code snippet, that should help you understand better

```
import datetime

liste = {'latest_time': datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 5, 0, 0), 'earliest_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 4, 0, 0)}
print(liste['latest_time'])

liste = {'latest_time': datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 5, 0, 0), 'earliest_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 4, 0, 0)}
```

OR

```
from datetime import datetime

liste = {'latest_time': datetime(2000, 1, 5, 0, 0), 'earliest_time': datetime(2017, 12, 4, 0, 0)}
print(liste['latest_time'])

liste = {'latest_time': datetime(2000, 1, 5, 0, 0), 'earliest_time': datetime(2017, 12, 4, 0, 0)}
```